# Input elements in Boostrap 4 modal are not postback in Asp.Net form

Tags: c#, asp.net, bootstrap-4

I have a form inside a Boostrap 4 modal. Inside there are 2 text input field and some hidden fields. When I submit the form the fields are not present in the Request.AllKeys collection.
I've check the Modal is inside the `<form>` tag, and this is confirmed also by the fact that the subit button it works perfectly, calling the method in the onclick event.
Here is the modal

```
<div class="modal fade" id="NewMsgModal" tabindex="-100" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-full modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h3 class="modal-title"><i class="icon-pencil7 mr-2"></i>
                New Message
            </h3>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true"><i class="icon-cross2 ml-2"></i></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body p-4" id="result">
            <input type="hidden" id="hidmsgreply" />
            <input type="hidden" id="hiddests" />
            <input type="hidden" id="hidtemp" />
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <label for="txtoggetto" class="text-teal-600">Subject</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-10 pb-1">
                    <input type="text" id="txtSubj" class="form-control">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 mb-2">
                    <textarea id="txtEditor">
                    </textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <span id="spanAutoSave"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer ">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>&nbsp;>&nbsp;<asp:Button ID="btnModel" runat="server" OnClick="btnmodel_Click" Text="Save Model" CssClass="btn btn-info" />&nbsp;<asp:Button ID="btnsend" runat="server" OnClick="btnsend_Click" OnClientClick="javascript: return validateMessage();" Text="Send" CssClass="btn btn-success" />
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

On the server, the method is called correctly but when I try to get the value of Request.Form["txtSubj"] or Request.Form["txtEditor"] it returns null.

The request.Form.AllKeys collection contains only the Asp.Net fields and the button used to submit

```
    Request.Form.AllKeys
{string[4]}
    [0]: "__VIEWSTATE"
    [1]: "__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR"
    [2]: "__EVENTVALIDATION"
    [3]: "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnsend"
```

I've notice that if the form is submitted using the btnModel button, it is added to the Request.Form.AllKeys and the brnsend is removed.

Any ideas?

Comment: add a name attribute to the inputs and set it to the same as the id. also make sure all the inputs are inside a forms tag.

Comment: Thanks Darkonekt, that solved the problem.

Comment: I would also make sure that the button you are using to "send" the form is actually of type submit.

Comment: I posted an answer. If this solved your issue would you be so kind to mark it as answered please.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following changes:

1. Add a name attribute to your inputs and set the value to same as the id.
2. Also make sure all the inputs are inside a forms tag.
3. Finally make sure the input or button being used to "send" the information is of type "submit."